# react-zoom-pan-pinch activation keys not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the [docs](https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page), activation keys should be a List of keys that, when held down, should activate the aforementioned feature.

However when I'm trying to set activation keys for zooming with [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch), it just disables the zoom altogether. The same goes for panning. Here's my code:

```
<TransformWrapper wheel={{activationKeys: ["alt"]}} >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to dig into the code and noticed that the library is using the `event.key` value.

According to this [W3 article](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboard-key-location) (referred to by MDN) you should be using the following key strings:

- `Shift`
- `Control`
- `Alt`
- `Meta` (e.g. Command on Mac)
- `ArrowDown`
- `ArrowLeft`
- `ArrowRight`
- `ArrowUp`
- `End`
- `Home`
- `PageDown`
- `PageUp`

and more.. (reference the link above)

In your specific case, you should capitalize `Alt`, such as:

```
<TransformWrapper wheel={{activationKeys: ["Alt"]}} >
```